# Super-Linter: Pass python modules as arguments to Pylint in Azure DevOps

Tags: python, azure-devops, lint, pylint, super-linter

I am trying to add a python linting step to an Azure DevOps pipeline using Super-Linter. I followed the instruction [here](http://blog.tyang.org/2020/06/27/use-github-super-linter-in-azure-pipelines/) to add the following step in my pipeline:

```
jobs:
- job: PythonLint
  displayName: Python Lint
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - script: |
      docker pull github/super-linter:latest
      docker run -e RUN_LOCAL=true -e VALIDATE_PYTHON_PYLINT=true -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/tmp/lint github/super-linter 
    displayName: 'Code Scan using GitHub Super-Linter'
```

The [Super-Linter github docs page](https://github.com/github/super-linter) describes passing environment variables to tell it which linters to run. I pass the variable `VALIDATE_PYTHON_PYLINT` to tell it to run pylint. When I run the pipeline, I get a load of errors of the form `E0401: Unable to import 'pyspark.sql' (import-error)`.

Pylint's [configuration page](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html?highlight=rcfile#command-line-options) says the modules should be passed as command line arguments.

My question is, how can I configure Super-Linter to pass these arguments or otherwise tell pylint which modules to import?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue. However, this is likely to be a super-linter issue, you'd better create a ticket on https://github.com/github/super-linter/issues to ask for help.

Comment: Issue created on GitHub https://github.com/github/super-linter/issues/499